# How do I navigate the page link to a specific div?

Tags: javascript, python, html, scrapy

Each time I access a URL, I got this.

[image]

The div pointed out by red square is shown by default.

To navigate the page I need, I have to click the div/span pointed by red arrow whose span is shown as below

```
<span data-blurb-id="708939" data-text-en="Teacher Feedback" data-woven="troopjs-ef/blurb/widget@309">CLASS REVIEW &amp; FEEDBACK</span>
```

When I click the link, chrome Network records this

[image]

> Request URL: https://cns.ef-cdn.com/_shared/gudstrap/1.1.1-ef.1/fonts//fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1

or this, sometimes 2 of them, sometimes 3 of them.

[image]

> Request URL: [https://ec.ef.com.cn/services/api/proxy/queryproxy?c=countrycode=cn|culturecode=en|partnercode=Cool|siteversion=26-1|studentcountrycode=cn|languagecode=en|devicetypeid=1|productid=100](https://ec.ef.com.cn/services/api/proxy/queryproxy?c=countrycode=cn%7Cculturecode=en%7Cpartnercode=Cool%7Csiteversion=26-1%7Cstudentcountrycode=cn%7Clanguagecode=en%7Cdevicetypeid=1%7Cproductid=100)

However, with the URL, I cannot access the page I want, How do I navigate the page link to the red arrow div?

Comment: please provide link to the website with div you described

Comment: Add an `<span id="mydivname"></span>` to the element you want to navigate and the go the the https://yoururl.cpm/#mydivname

Comment: @Roman Sorry, the link is only available for signed in user and cannot sign up by users themselves.

Comment: @Raffobaffo Thank you. Does the suggestion mean to change `<span data-blurb-id="708939" data-text-en="Teacher Feedback" data-woven="troopjs-ef/blurb/widget@309">CLASS REVIEW &amp; FEEDBACK</span>` to `<span id="mydivname data-blurb-id="708939" data-text-en="Teacher Feedback" data-woven="troopjs-ef/blurb/widget@309">CLASS REVIEW &amp; FEEDBACK</span>`?

Comment: Yes. Than you can navigate to that part just by appending a # with the name of the id. Like here, in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62715299/how-do-i-navigate-the-page-link-to-a-specific-div?noredirect=1#comment110906533_62715299

Comment: @Raffobaffo Thank you. The link is to this post itself.

Comment: Yes, on your comment

Comment: @Raffobaffo Sorry, I don't see your link or your answer.